# How do I render multiple views using Express and hbs?

Tags: express, backend

Currently I am trying to render multiple views. I have a beginning.hbs, a middle.hbs, and an end.hbs. My get Methods are below.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var part = require('../models/storyLine')

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
router.get('/storyline/:storyPart', function(req, res, next) {
  let beginning = part.storyLine.find(section => {
    return section.storyPart === req.params.storyPart
  })
  res.render('beginning', { beginning });
});
router.get('/storyline/:storyPart', function(req, res, next) {
  let middle = part.storyLine.find(section => {
    return section.storyPart === req.params.storyPart
  })
  res.render('middle', { middle });
});
router.get('/storyline/:storyPart', function(req, res, next) {
  let end = part.storyLine.find(section => {
    return section.storyPart === req.params.storyPart
  })
  res.render('end', { end });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have a storyLine.js file that I am pulling the data for the handlebars from.

```
module.exports.storyLine = [ 
    {
        storyPart: "beginning",
        name: "Rupert",
        animal: "fox",
        age: 8
    },
    {   
        storyPart: "middle",
        place: "France",
        travelVehicle: "train",
        YearsToStay: 2
    },
    {
        storyPart: "end",
        foxWife: "Amelle",
        housing: "a house next to the Eiffel Tower"
    }
]
```

The issue I am running into is the page is only rendering the beginning.hbs file no matter if I use the route. /storyline/end or /storyline/middle.

Any idea why I am unable to render multiple views utilizing the parameter :storyPart?

Thank you.

Comment: there are 3 routes with same name, It's not correct, change your approach

Comment: The route has a parameter though.